# How can I target Windows 10 IoT Core 17763 in a Visual Studio Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10-iot-core

My current version of Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard (1.0.1810.11000) allows for setting up a device with version 17763 of Windows 10 IoT Core.

[image]

In Visual Studio 2017 (15.87) though, I only have the option to target 17134 in my Universal Windows project (on the Application tab in the project settings page).

[image]

I worry about issues related to inconsistent versions. Is this justified? Or can I expect these versions to work together seamlessly?

I considered trying to get the IoT Dashboard to target the older version that Visual Studio is using but from what I understand, it will pretty much just keep jumping to the latest version with no option to target older versions. I saw somewhere that Windows IoT Enterprise allows for more control over versions. Do I need to go down that path if I want consistent versions between the Dashboard and Visual Studio? This [comparison](http://wincom.blob.core.windows.net/documents/Windows_10_IoT_Platform_Overview.pdf) would indicate that Core would otherwise be the best choice for my requirements?

Ideally, I would like some means of getting Visual Studio to target the new version. Is this possible? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), I was able to select version 17763 as the target version in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Yes,you cannot develop UWP apps for older versions of Windows, and you must have installed the appropriate build of the SDK in order to target that version.You can mark this as answer so that it will be helpful for who encounters the same issue.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Thanks for the feedback.